Thermodynamics of flow boiling in expanding cross section
Say you have some water flowing through a heat exchanger where sufficient heat is added to heat the water until it begins boiling. In a usual boiler the temperature and pressure is practically constant throughout the boiling process until the water becomes superheated vapour.  My question is what happens if the cross sectional area of the chanels that the water is flowing through isnt constant, but constantly expanding like a cone?
I understand that for a single phase fluid flowing through a pipe as you increase the cross sectional area the pressure will increase due to the flow slowing (Bernoulis equation), but will the pressure change the same way when the flow is boiling? I always learned in classes that pressure and temperature are constant during a phase change, but is this a situation where temperature and pressure change can occur during the phase change?

Beyond a certain location, you will have a combination of liquid and vapor flowing.
